# Changes do no show up on production running Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, passenger

Have got new project with production server already running on passenger.
After doing normal deploy as described in 1 page docs left by old team (only `cap prod deploy`) we are having constant problems. First of all - code we pushed doesn't seem to be working. It should be adding new data on rake tasks to items in database. Physically code is there - in current folder. But it doesnt seems to be triggered.
I ve noticed that there were no rails or gem installed when I ve tried to do simple `rails c` via ssh. After installing everything and manually launching code with `binding.pry` added looks like code was triggered. But via normal scheduled rake task it was not.
It looks like passenger is running in daemon since there are no pid in tmp folder (usual for rails app).

1) Is there a chance restarting server will actually help  - it was not restarted after deploy and I have no idea how to restart it without pid.

2)`passenger-config restart-app` returns actually 2 servers. Can they collide and prevent normal app work?(Update: servers are not same - single letter difference in the name)
Still `passenger-config restart-app` dont seem to restart server

Sorry for the wall of text by I ve spent 2 nights getting it to work and I still lost.

Comment: Please include the output from `passenger-config restart-app`.

Comment: Update: Was fixed after restarting Apache. `touch tmp/restart.txt`